# Converting a list of 3d matrix into 4d matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to write a function, which takes in a list of 3d matrices..

so.. each element in list have shape `(rows,cols, some_scalar).`.
I am trying to reshape it into 4d matrix.. 
so `output = (number_of_elements_in_matrix, rows,cols,some_scalar)`

so far I have is

```
output = np.zeros((len(list_of_matrices), list_of_matrices[0].shape[0], list_of_matrices[0].shape[1],
                      list_of_matrices[0].shape[2]), dtype=np.uint8)
```

How do i know fill this output 4d tensor with the values..

```
def reshape_matrix(list_of_matrices):
   output = np.zeros((len(list_of_matrices), list_of_matrices[0].shape[0], list_of_matrices[0].shape[1],
                          list_of_matrices[0].shape[2]), dtype=np.uint8)


   return output
```

Comment: @Divakar: yes.. that did the job.. if you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) to stack along the first axis (axis=0), like so -

```
np.stack(list_of_matrices,axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [22]: # Create an input list of arrays
    ...: arr1 = np.random.rand(4,5,2)
    ...: arr2 = np.random.rand(4,5,2)
    ...: arr3 = np.random.rand(4,5,2)
    ...: list_of_matrices = [arr1,arr2,arr3]
    ...: 

In [23]: np.stack(list_of_matrices,axis=0).shape
Out[23]: (3, 4, 5, 2)
```